# What is the name of the horizontal wooden piece between the wall and the floor in this image?

Tags: word-meaning, image-identification

What's the name of the horizontal wooden piece that separates the wall and floor, is there a technical name for it?

Thanks

[image: Wooden Piece]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We call that piece of wood the **[baseboard](https://kitchencabinetkings.com/glossary/baseboard/)**.

Comment: I suggest you add "also called skirting board (british english), skirting, mopboard, floor molding, or base molding" (from wikipeida)

Comment: Also, if taller, it's called [wainscoting](http://www.youguitarist.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Installing-Picture-Frame-Wainscoting.jpg)

Comment: Skirting board, in English. Though this example is shorter and thicker than most UK skirting boards.